# How to save objectId to other class in parse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

We have two classes `"User"` and `"Schools"`. Schools class contain `"objectId"` column.

I want to save `"objectId"` column to `"User"` in column `"currentSchool"` table but it is giving the following error:

> {"code":111,"error":"invalid type for key currentSchool, expected *Schools, but got string"}

Here is the code snippet:

```js
Parse.User.signUp(username, password,
{
    firstName: $scope.vm.form.firstName,
    lastName: $scope.vm.form.lastName,
    fullName: $scope.vm.form.firstName + " " + $scope.vm.form.lastName,
    email: email,
    onboardApplicantId: $scope.applicantId,
    currentSchool: schooolId,
    trainingStatus: "videos",
    videoStatus: 0,
    ACL: new Parse.ACL()
}, {
    success: function (user) {
        $("#signupForm").trigger('reset');
        console.log(' success ');
        $('.signupMsg').text("Account created successfully. Please verify your email address.");
        $('.submit-button').attr("disabled", false);
    },
    error: function (user, error) {
        $('.signupMsg').text(error.message);
        $('.submit-button').attr("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

Comment: didnt it occur you that you have to save Pointer and not string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I got the answer here it is :

I was doing this in "Parse.User.signUp" :

**currentSchool: schooolId,**

where it should be :

**currentSchool: {"__type": "Pointer", "className": "Schools", "objectId": schooolId},**

we need to pass the classname as well and need to define that it is a relation by type pointer it create relation between them.

I hope this will help to others as well.

Thanks guyz

Comment: The right way is to create a Parse Object and then set your objectId.   http://stackoverflow.com/a/39340938/5545574

Answer (score 0):

You have to create **School** object instance first, and then set the school objectId, after that set the school instance to the user's `currentSchool`. With these steps you will save a pointer of class School to you schoolId:

**Example:**

```
var SchoolClass = Parse.Object.extend("School");
var schoolObject = new SchoolClass();
schoolObject.set("objectId", schoolId);

Parse.User.signUp(username, password,
{
    firstName: $scope.vm.form.firstName,
    lastName: $scope.vm.form.lastName,
    fullName: $scope.vm.form.firstName + " " + $scope.vm.form.lastName,
    email: email,
    onboardApplicantId: $scope.applicantId,
    currentSchool: schoolObject,
    trainingStatus: "videos",
    videoStatus: 0,
    ACL: new Parse.ACL()
}, {
    success: function (user) {
        $("#signupForm").trigger('reset');
        console.log(' success ');
        $('.signupMsg').text("Account created successfully. Please verify your email address.");
        $('.submit-button').attr("disabled", false);
    },
    error: function (user, error) {
        $('.signupMsg').text(error.message);
        $('.submit-button').attr("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

@Mazel Tov is actually right:

If you take a look in your SCHEMA of DB (If you're running the open source version), else if you look at the "School" tab name in your User Table, you will see that the type of it is `School`.

It means that you need to send to Parse a `Parse.Object` representing a school and not the id of it :) (because the id is a String and that's where your error is coming from)

**So to fix it:**

*Option 1*: You fetched the list of the schools you had and you can just pass them to Parse again.

*Option 2*: You change the type of School by removing the column and readding it again as `String` type.

Comment: thanks for reply..... well option 2 I can't do that can you please explain option 1 in brief that how do I pass them to parse again as I'm new to parse...

please suggest

Comment: 1) You can do it  without fetching.